# python bytecode interpreter implementation

Tags: python, bytecode

i am following a tutorial [here](http://www.aosabook.org/en/500L/a-python-interpreter-written-in-python.html) which is about implementing a simple stack based python byte code interpreter .

i am having problem in this funciton :

```
def parse_byte_and_args(self):
    .........
    if byteCode >= dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT: #<-----------------------this part
```

what exactly is `dis.HACE_ARGUMENT` ? since its a big function i thought not to post it here rather give link to it.if its required let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of the function you are defining, you're trying to process an opcode (instruction) which may or may not have arguments associated with it.

If you look at the [Python disassembler documentation for HAVE_ARGUMENT](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-HAVE_ARGUMENT), you'll see that dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT is used exactly for this purpose.

That is, if byteCode >= dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT, the the opcode has arguments and you need to figure out what to do with them.  Otherwise, the opcode has no arguments and there's no extra processing required.

Take care, because according to the documentation I linked above, this changed slightly as of Python 3.6

Comment: thanks, i got it now. can you suggest any other source for learning a byte code interpreter

Comment: that function also has this statement  `arg_val = arg[0] + (arg[1] * 256)`. why multiplication by 256?

Comment: During my brief period of writing interpreters, I found it helpful to look at two different types of resources:  Generic resources which explained the concepts (such as wikipedia, etc.), and specific resources which involved someone's own bespoke implementation.  Examples of the latter: [Extensible Interpreter Development Kit](http://www.parsifalsoft.com/examples/xidek/xidek/doc/bcidefs.htm)  and [My Most Important Project Was a Bytecode Interpreter](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12553591)

Comment: In answer to your second question, multiplying by 256 is the same as bit-shifting to the left by 8 bits, so `arg[0] + (arg[1] * 256)` concatenates the bits of `arg[1]` together with the bits of `arg[0]`